# what is the purpose of LogInstanc in AIT1 table?

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I need to find my current item price and last history price, but I do not know how to create query because I don't really know what LogInstanc is for? Because I want use it for compare in table aitm, itm1, ait1. Then by using sql server management 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogInstanc is an incrementing number indicating the version number of the row. It starts at 1 and increments for each record version written to the table. There's a maximum history setting (in company settings) and once this number is reached the oldest rows will be deleted.

For the AITM table, both LogInstanc and ItemCode define the primary key.

For each row in AITM, you can have zero or more matching rows in AIT1. For this table, LogInstanc, ItemCode and PriceList are the primary key.

Here's an example that shows the current and last prices for all items, for price list 1:

```
SELECT itemcode
       ,(
              SELECT TOP 1 price
              FROM itm1
              WHERE itm1.itemcode = oitm.itemcode
                     AND pricelist = 1
              ) AS currentprice
       ,(
              SELECT TOP 1 price
              FROM ait1
              WHERE ait1.itemcode = oitm.itemcode
                     AND pricelist = 1
              ORDER BY LogInstanc DESC
              ) AS lastprice
FROM oitm
```